# How to find volume of arbitrary polyhedron?

Tags: python, scipy

I have been trying to find the volume of an arbitrary polyhedron using scipy `spatial.ConvexHull()`.

My data is imported as an xyz array of points and the polyhedron looks like this:

[image: xyz surface plot]

Currently, scipy `ConvexHull` is giving me a volume of 4806 which is clearly too large.  Any other methods for calculating the volume of an arbitrary polyhedron would be great.

Comment: Hi Nick, can you produce a triangle mesh from the data? If so, then computing the volume is simple: https://github.com/sjhalayka/qjs-isosurface/blob/6385aa846b0733761e4dcdcb505fe6fefc87be7f/mesh.cpp#L273

Comment: Your polyhedron is bounded by a box of size 25 x 12.5 x 25 = ~7800. A volume of 4806 doesn't seem that unreasonable.